# Index exceeds matrix dimensions popup error

Tags: matlab

I am trying to do an approximation of 1/e

I keep getting an error saying index exceeds matrix dimensions. Why?

```
n = 0;
eqn = 0;

while abs(eqn - (1/exp(1))) > .0001
n = n+1;
eqn = (1 - (1/n))^n;

end

nsav = n;
appr = eqn;
builtin = 1/exp(1);
fprintf ('The built in value is %.4f\n' , builtin)
fprintf ('The approximation is %.4f\n', appr)
fprintf ('The value of n required for such accuracy is %d\n', nsav)
```

Comment: Which line is the problem?

Comment: I don't know. How do I identify it?

Comment: The output comes out correctly in eveyry other respect. I have been trying all day to figure out why I keep getting errors.

Comment: The error message should say.

Comment: It doesn't The error pops up in another window

Comment: Not the command window

Comment: `builtin` is a Matlab function - use a different name for that variable.

Comment: The only thing that would cause that error in this code if `exp=[];`, as far as I can tell.  Type `whos exp`.... or `abs`.

Comment: Nope. Still get error when I change variable name to b

Comment: Type `whos` and make sure `abs` and `exp` aren't listed.

Comment: Ok. I typed whos. They weren't listed. But I did a clear all anyways and a clc. It works now. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

This answer doesn't really solve the user's problem. But since what the user wanted was a loop to approximate 1/e, here are some possibilities:

One quick approach:

```
tic
N = 1e6;
N1 = 1;
N2 = N1 + N - 1;
err_exp = 1e-7;
ctrl = 1;
while ctrl
  n = N1:N2; eqn = (1 - (1 ./ n)) .^ n;
  inds = find(abs(eqn - 1/exp(1)) < err_exp, 1, 'first');
  if ~isempty(inds)
    ctrl = 0;
  else
    N1 = N1 + N;
    N2 = N1 + N - 1;
  end
end
fprintf('n must be at least %d\n', N1 + inds - 1)
toc
% Elapsed time is 0.609669 seconds.
```

A better approach is the dichotomic search:

```
tic
N = 1e6;
a = 1 / exp(1);
err_exp = 1e-15;
ctrl = 1;
n = 1;
% 1º Step: find starting values for n1 and n2
while ctrl
  eqn = (1 - (1 / n)) ^ n;
  ctrl = abs(eqn - a) > err_exp;
  if ctrl
    n1 = n;
    n = 2 * n;
  end
end
n2 = n;

% 2º step: search dichotomically between the extremes
ctrl = 1;
while ctrl
  if n2 - n1 < N
    n = n1:n2; eqn = (1 - (1 ./ n)) .^ n;
    n = find(abs(eqn - a) < err_exp, 1, 'first');
    eqn = eqn(n);
    n = n1 + n - 1;
    ctrl = 0;
  else
    n = floor((n1 + n2 + 1) / 2);
    eqn = (1 - (1 / n)) ^ n;
    chck = abs(eqn - a) > err_exp;
    if chck
      n1 = n;
    else
      n2 = n;
    end
  end
end
toc
% Elapsed time is 0.231897 seconds.

[abs(eqn - a), err_exp]
[n1 n n2]
```

Just for the fun of it.

Comment: it would, but I am asked specifically to use a while loop.

Comment: No, please, don't do it - look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Type `whos` and make sure `abs` and `exp` aren't listed.  If they are listed as variables, clear them with:

```
clear abs whos
```

Then make sure there is no where else above this code that sets `abs` and `whos` as variables.

For the record, it seems there is some strange version-specific popup error that happens when you do `builtin=exp(1)`.  David pointed this out. Unfortunately, I can't reproduce it with R2013b 64-bit.

Comment: That's odd! I'm sure it was the `builtin` part, but if it was still in your workspace as a variable then a `clear` would remove it.

Comment: @David He wasn't indexing `builtin` though.  You can use it as a variable, although it is bad practice.

Comment: @David Well, I guess no one gets any credit for this odd one.  Seriously, I want to see a popup error!  :D

Comment: @chappjc I was getting the popup error, never seen one before! It's weird actually, with a clear workspace, typing `builtin=exp(1)` gives the popup error.

Comment: @David - I just get `>> builtin=exp(1)
builtin =
    2.7183`  I really want to see this popup.  What version do you have?

Comment: @chappjc R2012b. It prints the answer like that, but gives the popup as well.

Comment: @David - I'd say make a screenshot and post it as an answer. It's hard to argue with a picture.

Answer (score 1):

OK so if I run this code

```
a=exp(1)

clear

builtin=exp(1)
```

I get

```
a =
    2.7183
builtin =
    2.7183
```

and this error

[image]

However if I run this code

```
a=exp(1)

clear

builtin=exp(1)

clear

a=exp(1)
```

I get no error!

This is R2012b on Mac OSX.

Comment: That is quite a unique... feature?  I wonder if it is Mac specific.

Comment: @chappjc No it isn't, I have exact the same behaviour on R2013a/Win8